# Have problem converting GlmNet vec3 to glm vec3 in Cli/C++

Tags: glm-math

I need to convert GlmNet::vec3 to C++ glm::vec3 in my cli/c++ wrapper, but if I add the GlmNet reference in my project, a compiler error occurred said the glm::vec3 is ambiguous. Anyone has clue for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by creating a alias for the glm namespace.